# How to find the PID of nginx process

Tags: ps

I am trying to fix a problem with nginx and think that there is an nginx process running on my machine. When I run this command I get this output.

```
$ ps aux -P | grep nginx
1000      3947  0.0  0.0  13596   932 pts/0    S+   14:05   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

But if I try to kill processes 1000, 3947, 13596 or 932 I get errors like:

`bash: kill: (1000) - No such process`

What's going on? How do I find and kill the nginx process?

Answer (score 9):

I usually find `pgrep` more convenient than `ps | grep`. You might also want to look at `killall` if the end goal is blasting a bunch of processes by name.

Comment: +1 I prefer it, too. I guess you don't see it around much because it relies on having `/proc`, so it's less portable than a vanilla `ps | grep`.

Answer (score 6):

`ps aux -P` shows these columns:

```
$ ps aux -P | head -1
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

Only the 2nd column is the pid.

Warning: don't try to kill random pids.

pid 3947 was the grep process that ended when you got your prompt back, so there truly is no such process.

If there was an nginx process, you would have seen it in the grep output. Conclusion: nginx is not running on your machine.

Answer (score 5):

A common trick to avoid the `grep` command itself from showing up in `ps` output is to put the first character in a character class so that it won't match its literal self.  I.e.,

```
$ ps aux | grep [n]ginx
```

This way the `grep` pattern will match "nginx" but not the literal "[n]ginx" that shows up in the `ps` output.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I try to kill processes 1000, 3947, 13596 or 932 I get errors like [...]

in the output of `ps`, 1000 is the user ID of the process (`grep` in that case), 3947 is the PID of `grep`, and the other numbers are status parameter values and not at all PIDs.

If you want to see all processes by name, then use something like

```
ps -lfC nginx
```

caveat: you have to know the exact name, otherwise ps doesn't return anything. If you don't know the exact name, then use `pgrep`.

Answer (score 2):

Very often you must use `sudo` for managing `nginx` process. Prepend all the commands below with `sudo` if you got 'Operation is not permitted' error. Although this question is tagged as 'ps' I'd like to mention the other opportunities.

In case you just want to stop nginx I would recommend using:

```
service nginx stop
```

But if your purpose is to find 'pid' itself (to send a signal for example) I'd recommend looking for `nginx.pid`. Once nginx is started it puts it's pid into this file.

> `nginx` can be controlled with signals. The process ID of the master process is written to the file /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid by default

It might be somewhere else, though.

In case you have [compiled nginx by youself](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) you could have specified `pid-path` as well.

> `--pid-path=path` — sets the name of an `nginx.pid` file that will store the process ID of the main process. After installation, the file name can always be changed in the nginx.conf configuration file using the pid directive. By default the file is named prefix/logs/nginx.pid

Otherwise you can specify path to pid file explicitly in `nginx.conf`.

Read about [Nginx Control](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html)

So, to send a signal just type:

```
kill `cat /path/to/nginx.pid`
```

Or

```
kill $(cat /path/to/nginx.pid)
```

Read about [killing the process by pid file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107090/kill-process-by-pid-file).

Personally, writing script or deployment instructions I wouldn't entrust stopping or searching nginx pid on `pgrep` and especially on `grep`, though they are applicable on the local machine. But in this case I would shorten stopping to `pkill` (process kill):

```
pkill nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

on most nginx installs you can find the pid on the file system: `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`

Answer (score 0):

To kill all the nginx processes you could do:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'nginx' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run this command:**

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'nginx' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: This looks a bit dangerous, you might end up killing many more processes than you intend to. Plus, using SIGKILL (-9) when it's not absolutely necessary is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try using this command

```
ps -ax | grep nginx
```

You will be getting the first process id with master process mentioned and then use that id to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

First, identify the *master* process:

```
$ ps -ef |grep nginx
root     1394258       1  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 1394265 1394258  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

Then, to shut down operations, use the QUIT signal to "gracefully" kill the master process:

```
$ sudo kill -QUIT 1394258
```